# How should I solve $2^x=4x$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I am trying this math to solve.the equation is like this:

$2^x=4x$

Here $x=4$ should be the answer.

**But How can I derive it in a mathematical way?**

I am failed to solve it my general algebra.How can I use logarithm here to solve it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note: $x=4$ is not the only solution to this equation. There's another one at $x\approx0.3099$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$2^x=4x$$
$$\frac14=x\cdot0.5^x$$
$$\frac14=xe^{x\ln0.5}$$
$$\frac1{4\ln0.5}=x\ln0.5e^{x\ln0.5}$$

Taking $u=x\ln0.5$:

$$ue^u=\frac1{4\ln0.5}$$

This equation cannot be solved in elementary terms. However, [the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $\operatorname W(z)$ is defined such that it is the inverse of $ze^z$. Thus:

$$u=\operatorname W\left(\frac1{4\ln0.5}\right)$$
$$x\ln0.5=\operatorname W\left(\frac1{4\ln0.5}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{\operatorname W\left(\frac1{4\ln0.5}\right)}{\ln0.5}$$

This gives us [$x\approx0.309907$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product+Log%28ln0.5%2F4%29%2Fln%280.5%29).

---

Alternatively, if you want to use repetitive methods to calculate $2^x=4x$, then we define $f(x)=2^x-4x$. Now, we need to find $f(x)=0$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is:

$$\frac d{dx}\left[2^x-4x\right]$$
$$=\frac d{dx}\left[2^x\right]-\frac d{dx}[4x]$$
$$=\ln2\cdot2^x-4$$

By Newton's method, we have

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{2^{x_n}-4x}{\ln2\cdot2^{x_n}-4}$$

Now given any initial guess $x_0$ we can use this iterative function to gain an approximation.